# Running vscode task that includes which fails

Tags: bash, visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I have a task created that runs some unittests via bash_unit.
The bash unit script seems to fail based on its use of which.
If I replace:

```
CAT="$(which cat)"
```

and other which referances in bash unit to point to my local commands all runs great.

If I run bash)unit directly all good, but if i run it as a vscode task it fails.

I have simplified the task below to the minimum failure:

```
{
// See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
// for the documentation about the tasks.json format
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
    {
        "label": "run which",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "/usr/bin/which which",
        "problemMatcher": [],
        "group": "test",
    }
]
```

}

This produces the following:

```
The terminal process "/bin/bash '-c', '/usr/bin/which which'" failed to launch (exit code: 1).
```

Any ideas what is happening?